# How can i build an app with Flash Builder that auto adjust the size of each item

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

In Flash Builder does there exist some property that works similar to `WRAP_CONTENT`, `FILL_PARENT` and `MATCH_PARENT` of Android?

Answer (score 0):

Flash builder does not have such properties as such, and Flex containers typically achieve this by using percentages for the width and height attributes. For example:

```
<s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Rect width="50%" height="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xff6600"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
```

will create a container of width 100% (respective to it's parent) and height 100%, and the orange rectangle within this container will be 50% of it's parent's width, and height 100%.

So, if the container is 500px, the orange rectangle will be 250px (50%) of its width.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Victor, does my explanation answer your question? If yes, please select the answer as an accepted answer and close the question. Thanks